# iPhone 5 device launching app as an iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone

I´ve made an app, and I tested it on my iPhone 5, iOS 8.1.2 It worked perfectly there, however when i tested it on my fathers iPhone 5s, iOS 7.1.2, the top and bottom of the screen were cut off, as if it was tested on an iPhone 4. Does anyone know what could cause this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need the 4" launch image. You must have the launch screen file which only works on iOS 8. iOS 7 requires the standard launch images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your launch screen image **Default-568h@2x.png** to your project and set it to the Asset Catalog. This will work in both **iOS 7** and **iOS 8**